# How do I get a reference to the Application object of a UserForm?

Tags: vba, excel

If I want to write a `Sub` that positions a `UserForm` relative to the `Application` object that displays it, How would I go about doing it?

I want to write a sub that goes like this:

```
Sub PositionForm(WhichForm as Object)
WhichForm.Left = <WhichForm Application Object>.Left
End Sub
```

I understand that there are many workarounds to this. I am interested in knowing whether there is a way to getting that reference.

Answer (score 1):

in Excel the following works:

```
Sub PositionForm(WhichForm As Object)
    WhichForm.Left = Application.Left
End Sub
```

to be called from any UserForm code as:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

   ... any code

    PositionForm Me

    ... any code

End Sub
```

Comment: I want to control a user form in another instance of excel. Your code will position it based on the "parent" instance, not the instance in which the form was opened. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Actually I don't know since I never used such a feature. But should that be the case, you could store in a `Public` variable the application instance you want to refer to and then use it

Comment: I realise I can pass the form and the application to the sub. Thank you for giving me that idea. It'd still be nice to somehow extract a reference to the application that created a form, from the form object itself.

Comment: That latter I wouldn’t know. But if you get it you’d be welcome to post here. As for the very subject of your question if my answer solved it please consider marking as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I will wait for someone to suggest a way to extract the reference. I'm up voting your answer now.